Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop After Upgrade GD Library is not loading
Ubuntu Desktop 24.04, after upgrading this PC a few days ago from 23.10 I found that the GD library is no longer working. I tried reinstalling with sudo apt install --reinstall php-gd, then purging and reinstalling with sudo apt purge php-gd and sudo apt install php-gd but to no avail. PHP is version 8.3.
Running this also shows that it is not running.
php -i | grep -i gd

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20230831/gd.so (libdav1d.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20230831/gd.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20230831/gd.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
/etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
GDMSESSION => ubuntu
$_SERVER['GDMSESSION'] => ubuntu

The gd.so file is right where it says it's looking in /usr/lib/php/20230831/gd.so but I don't know what the reference to libdav1d.so is or the odd references to gd.so.so.
What's going on and how can I get it going?

php's gd.so is presumably a wrapper around libgd.so.3 - so you may want to check the installation status of the libgd3 package

@steeldriver That makes sense. However, trying to install it, it said: libgd3 is already the newest version (2.3.3-9ubuntu5). libgd3 set to manually installed. I ran sudo apt install -f then sudo apt install libgd3 and no more manually installed messages. However, after restarting Apache, GD still does not work.

Anyone? A regular install does not work and no errors either other than the gd library being missing. There are no more system updates either other than the usual ones from time to time although the upgrade from 23.10 to 24.04 did not go smoothly so is there some way to check that everything is there as far as the basic system itself is concerned?

Sorry I don't really know anything about php - one odd thing is the mention of libdav1d.so.6 since AFAIK 24.04 uses libdav1d7 (i.e. libdav1d.so.7) - indeed apt depends --recurse libgd3 shows a dependency on libdav1d7 (via libheif1 -> libheif-plugin-dav1d). If you can install the lddtree package then lddtree  /usr/lib/php/20230831/gd.so may be helpful. It might be worth trying apt install --reinstall libgd3 libdav1d7.

... fwiw I suspect the message about gd.so.so is just (because having failed to load gd.so) there's just an algorithmic rule that says "stick .so on the given name and try again"

@steeldriver Thank you for that and I think I had tried it but just ran again. It's not a 24.04 issue per se as it's running on my two other Ubuntu 24.04 PCs and did so without issue. I tried today a reinstall of Apache but did it as an install --reinstall rather than first purging and installing it which I am hesitant to do as I don't think it will help. The weird thing is why is it looking at gd.so but not loading it? Instead it gives an error that it can't be found.

It seems to fall back to not loading gd.so for whatever reason. From the Apache log: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20230831/gd.so . . . even though the file is there. Looking at its properties, it shows it was accessed today but whether that was PHP trying to load it or my checking the properties is unclear. In any event, I can see no reason why it says it can't locate it when it's looking right at it. It makes no sense!

Have you tried a simple command-line test like php -r 'print_r(gd_info());' ?

Yes, using the simpler php -i | grep ini all it shows are all the cli files loading including 20-gd.so. Using gd_info() gives all the same errors that gd isn't loaded.

I forgot to mention that the Apache error log says that the error is in Unknown on line 0 which makes no sense.
